# Using form.submit to validate checkbox section

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I have a form with a name that is passed to the controller, and when the form is $valid I continue to process data. This used to work with radio buttons, but when I switched to checkboxes, the validation passes only when all checkboxes are selected. How can I make it so, selecting 1 makes the form valid?
Code snippet for reference:

```
<form name="snippetForm" ng-submit="vm.submitForm(snippetForm)" novalidate>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination.1" ng-true-value="'1'" name="location" required >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination.2" ng-true-value="'2'" name="location" required >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination.3" ng-true-value="'3'" name="location" required >
</form>

vm.submitForm = function(form) {
    if(form.$valid) {
        console.log('Passes only when all checkboxes from form.location are selected')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `ng-change` expression on each check-box. The expression will set the form invalid if no check-box is selected.

```
<form name="snippetForm" ng-submit="vm.submitForm(snippetForm)" novalidate>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination1" ng-true-value="'1'" name="location" ng-change="{{(!vm.destination1 && !vm.destination2 && !vm.destination3) ? (snippetForm.$valid = false) : (snippetForm.$valid = snippetForm.$valid)}}" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination2" ng-true-value="'2'" name="location" ng-change="{{(!vm.destination1 && !vm.destination2 && !vm.destination3) ? (snippetForm.$valid = false) : (snippetForm.$valid = snippetForm.$valid)}}" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.destination3" ng-true-value="'3'" name="location" ng-change="{{(!vm.destination1 && !vm.destination2 && !vm.destination3) ? (snippetForm.$valid = false) : (snippetForm.$valid = snippetForm.$valid)}}" >
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for help, but with checkboxes this has a side effect, so I had to give the elements distinct ng-model name. The way it is now, selecting one will mark all checkboxes as checked

Comment: Well, yeah, I started with radio, until it turned out that there can be more than 1 location selected, so I need to use the checkboxes - which now wont let me validate the form, what do?

Comment: sorry, I dont think thats a good solution. If I had more than 3 checkboxes this ternary would look ridiculous. Plus, selecting 1 checkbox would force the form to become valid, even if other input fields had errors in it. 
I think this could be solved bymodifying built in validators, but its too big of a hussle for me to do right now. Will let know if I come up with something.

Comment: @lukiwolski There are no input fields than 3 checkboxes. Plus I've updated the code